# How to understand the 'unmanifested karma' before the creation?

Tags: mahabharata, karma, panchabhoota

Consider the following verses regarding the Mula prakruthi

> **अव्यक्तकर्मजा** बुद्धिर अहंकारं परसूयते
>
> आकाशं चाप्य अहंकाराद वायुर आकाशसंभवः
>
> वायॊस तेजस ततश चापस तव अद्भ्यॊ हि वसुधॊद्गता
>
> मूलप्रकृतयॊ ऽसतौ ता जगद एतास्व अवस्थितम
>
> From the **Unmanifest** flows the Understanding determined by **acts**. The
> Understanding produces Consciousness. From Consciousness proceeds
> Space. From Space proceeds Wind. From the Wind proceeds Heat. From
> Heat proceeds Water, and from Water is produced the Earth. These eight
> constitute primordial Prakriti. The universe rests on them.
>
> [[25-26](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs12203.htm)[, Section 210, Mokshadharma Parva,  Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b037.htm)

These two verses show the sequence of steps of creation till Jagath/universe. The sequence is shown below

```
Unmanifest karma (1) -> Buddhi (2) -> Ahamkara/conciousness (3) -> Akasa/space  (4) -> Vayu/wind (5) -> Agni/Heat (6) -> water (7) -> earth (8)
```

I want to know about the first one: unmanifested karma i.e, **अव्यक्तकर्म**.

I think the verses mentioned above are refers to a *jiva* as subsequent verses are hinting the same

> From those Eight have originated the five organs of knowledge, the
> five organs of action, the five objects of the (first five) organs,
> and the one, viz., the Mind, forming the sixteenth, which is the
> result of their modification.

Am I true? If yes, what does the unmanifested karma here refer to? Is the **collection of karma from all the past lives** that are leading to birth?

Comment: You are right here. It is the collection of karma of all the past lives that is the unmanifested karma and that drives the next manifestation of the universe.

Comment: Yes jiva exist forever before creation and after creation each have their innert nature that swabhavika karma even tough environment and societal compulsion make them act differently for e.g karna